# Show feature of dropdown when an img is clicked in jquery mobile

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

Could you please let me know how can a img on a click open drop down, and when the user selects the item from the dropdown, the img should come back.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you are making to work?

Comment: I have no clue of how to code this, i guess its in the css work to show hide the img on the click, am not sure

Comment: you can uses the popup widget: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/ look at the menu example...